# Why am I getting an error? (syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

This is the errors I am getting :

> syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end @subscripting.send(name) = false ^

Here is my code:

View

```
<% if @subscripting.send(service.name) == true %>
    <p>done</p>
    <p>password<%= service.password %></p>
    <%= link_to "cancel", cancel_path(service_name: service.name), :method => :post %>
<% else %>
```

controller

```
def cancel
    name = params[:service_name]
    @subscripting = Subscripting.find_by(user_id: @current_user.id)
    @subscripting.send(name) = false
end
```

Thank you very much for answer and help.

Comment: To call a setter use `@subscripting.send("#{name}=", false)` – the `=`  is part of the method name.

Comment: Why are you even using `send` here? Using `send` with user input is really dangerous especially if you are not whitelisting the input.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Object.send` you pass arguments to the method as secondary arguments. See documentation https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-i-send

So instead try:

```
def cancel
  name = params[:service_name]
  @subscripting = Subscripting.find_by(user_id: @current_user.id)
  @subscripting.send(name, false)
end
```

But if params are coming from some user input this could be dangerous and you should consider using [Strong Parameters](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)